# How to call static method overridden by child class in "typescript"?

Tags: php, typescript

I want to invoke a static method in typescript, from the parent class implementation, ensuring the method is replaced by inheritance in any child class.

In PHP it is possible to use the word "static" as if it were the word "self". See more [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/new-self-vs-new-static-in-php/).

As far as I know, in typescript, to invoke a static method or access a static property, you must explicitly name the class. However, from a parent class, I have no way of knowing the name of the child class.

Example:

```js
class myClass {
  private static propA: any[] = ["a", "b"];

  public myMehod(): Promise<any[]> {
    return new Promise<any[]>((res) => {
      /* call the eventually overridden static method */
      let x: any[] = static.getter(); // << here need
      /* ... */
      res(x);
    });
  }


  public static getter(): any[] {
    return this.propA;
  }
}

export class childClass extends myClass {
  private static probB: any[] = [1, 2, 3];

  /* overridden static method, which is invoked by the parent */
  public static getter(): any[] {
    return myClass.getter().concat(this.probB);
  }
}

(new childClass()).myMehod().then((r) => console.log(r));
// show: ["a", "b", 1, 2, 3];
```

How to do this in typescript?

Comment: I don't know if it works in all cases and situations, but what I did: replaces `static...` for `(this.constructor as typeof myClass)...`.